# How to get the default value from a table in SQL

Tags: sql

There are two tables in SQL, `Parcel` and `Status`. The `Parcel` table has a relationship with `Status`.

- [Status table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Zr0H.png)
- [Parcel table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y9eTs.png)

I want the `Awaiting` column from the `Status` table to be selected by default in the `Parcel` column which is called `Status`.

I just want to select the a value by default from another table in SQL.

Comment: Show what you have attempted so far.

Answer (score 0):

This is a query you can select:

```
SELECT 
 s.awaiting as awaiting_status
,p.*
FROM
parcel_table as p
join status_table as s
on s.statusID = p.ParcelStatus
```

if you want your parcel_table to have status from status_table selected, you must have this created on the front-end of your application.
In database, you create a primary key and foreign key!

```
CREATE table parcel_status (
parcelID BIGINT NOT NULL primary key
,ParcelStatus INT NOT NULL
,parcelAddres VARCHAR(500)
,PRIMARY KEY (parcelID)
,CONSTRAINT FK_PersonOrder FOREIGN KEY (ParcelStatus)
REFERENCES parcel_status(ID)
```

and create a foreign key on status table:

```
CREATE TABLE status_table (
 ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
,statusDescription ...
)
```